# Slow SQL, need assistance. should I go in memory?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, caching

Ive recently spun up an application (java 8, spring-boot, hibernate, maven) that exposes a database via rest api. The problem I am having is that the database calls are slow (3000 ms+) JUST to get one row.

My table looks like this: (6m rows, 210Mb, InnoDB, MySQL)

```
 Row    |  Type   |   length

 id     |  int    |   10 

 start  |  int    |   10 

 end    |  int    |   10

 rec_id |  int    |   11 - primary key
```

and my sql is:

```
WHERE start < x AND end > x
```

but in Hibernate convention:

```
BlocksEntity findByStartLessThanAndEndGreaterThan(int start, int end)
```

where start and end are the same value

I get that this BETWEEN (well > and < for Hibernate) is probably a really expensive operation.
So, since this was so slow, I started looking into in memory tables since:

- I ONLY ever need to READ from the database, NOT make updates to it
- The data in the database hardly ever changes, we are talking once a month maybe

What would be the best way to proceed here? I really need this to be as responsive as possible as it will be delivering content to a web page that has a quick time-out.  I thought about caching, but since I will be caching the result on the user endpoint, any cache here would never be hit. Also, the key (x) is way too unique to cache and most likely will not be hit.

There are other tables as well that I read from but this one is the most problematic.  Any help and suggestions will be truly appreciated.

Comment: You have indexes? You have not mentioned the word at all ...

Comment: Move the content of the table into memory, then do the queries against your table in memory rather than to your database. This will improve the performance. And don't use second level cache from Hibernate since that will query the database first.

Comment: @AlexK. No, unfortunately, there are no indexes on the table. I wish there were, but its not my data.

Comment: So you can't add em? Or import into a DB that does have them?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza How would you implement this? Loading the data on startup from a csv or straight from the database into a map or object list and then search for the rows there? Or something like in memory H2 database?

Comment: In my case, I load the data and store it depending on how I will query it. For example, if I will seek for exact keys, then use a `Map`, if requesting a range of data, then a `TreeMap` or a heap. Search for the best approach for your specific case.

Comment: Do you have indices on `start` and `end`? Also, well, this is typically where Hibernate only ever restricts your expressiveness. If you can try and use [jooq](http://www.jooq.org) instead.

Comment: @AlexK. I might be able to add indexes. I'm porting this information over to my own database soon, so adding indexes is an option. Can i expect a significant performance increase if this is added? Im not 100% comfortable with how they would be used in this case.

Comment: @fge No, but this is something I am going to look into, hoping there would be significant performance increases if this happens, but it would have to go from 3000ms to sub 50ms

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks for the suggestions, im going to look into this right now.

Comment: @user3258271 with jooq you can definitely get into these figures. If you think 6 million rows is huge, then have a look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayWlXzvC9s8)... And note that I use an on-the-fly, file-based H2 RDBMS instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a composite index on (start, end) will solve your issue.

your table size is huge (6m rows) but looking at the columns you don't have Text fields so in my opinion just by adding indexes your issue will be solved especially that you don't have frequent updates so your indexes statistics will always be up to date.

I would have recommended to use ehcache with hibernate for caching entities but in this case, in my opinion you don't need it. You might need it in other cases.

If the indexes did not help (which I don't think will be the case) then it might be due to the index cardinality. I don't think it s your data case just pointing to this.

Another items to take into consideration:

- Since your Data is mostly for read I suggest you use MyISAM engine instead of InnoDB if this is not the case already.
- Finally, I don't know what findByStartLessThanAndEndGreaterThan SQL output is, but I suggest you set show_sql to true in your hibernate configuration and check the real SQL generated. Based on this you can use a better HQL query if needed

Comment: 6 million rows is not "huge". It's barely average ;)

Comment: Thanks for your useful reply, in my small experience in web application and in db tuning I would have considered it as huge.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to add a comment about my ehcache sentence above. Reading it I think it gives the impression that using ehcache is recommended for similar cases. Well normally we use it for small entities that rarely change and not the case above. So it is good to use it with Hibernate but I would use it to cache small tables

Comment: Well, that's the problem with ORMs which think that the O matters more than the R whereas the opposite is true :) I don't use Hibernate specifically for that reason. JooQ, on the other hand, allows you to fully harness the R in RDBMS, no cache needed :p The RDBMS does all the job for you

Comment: I did not look at JooQ but will certainly look at it. To be fair the problem above is not hibernate's it is clearly the missing indexes, so even if he tries to run native SQL he will have the qry slow. That is why I mentioned that he extracts the query generated by hibernate. If he had db knowledge he would have explained the qry and found the bottleneck ie: if data does not fit in memory therefore it is written on disk or a full table scan is done (which is his case since no indexes). I am not saying that hibernate does not drive you insane sometimes, but for this case Hibernate is innocent;)